# Positioning of my #content div not working?

Tags: html, css

Whenever I put in the HTML for my webpage; the `#content div` is below the widget/sidebar and I already tried `position:absolute`- and that causes my images to not re-size.

```
#content {
    background: #fff;
    margin: 2px 0 2px;
    padding: 20px 62px;
    width: 68%;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 25%;
    /* rounded corner */
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    /* box shadow */
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #000000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #000000;
}

/************************************************************************************
SIDEBAR
*************************************************************************************/
#sidebar {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    margin: 2px 0 2px;
}
.widget {
    background: #0b2d7e;
    margin: 0 0 0px;
    padding: 0px 20px;
    /* rounded corner */
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    /* box shadow */
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #000000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #000000;
}
```

Comment: setup an example (jsfiddle) to show your problem so we can figure out the alignment issue..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/a2YSa/

Answer (score 1):

Same lesson I tried to teach you earlier.  You're stuff doesn't add up to 100% because of the paddings.  You have 68% + 25% + 25% + more padding = way more than 100%.

If a box is 50% wide and it has a padding of 10px on the left and right, and a 1px border, then you have 50% +20px+2px.

If you have two divs exactly the same as above you have 100% +40px +40px +2px +2px = more than 100%.

Use `box-sizing: border-box;` to solve your padding and border problem above.  Then you just have to take into account the margins.

See the [Can I Use It](http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing) for box-sizing.

Here is a JS Fiddle fixing your code... You also had a stray `</aside>` that wasn't needed.

http://jsfiddle.net/a2YSa/1/

Note that in the code I provided, `box-sizing: border-box;` tells the div to calculate its width including padding and borders.  Then I have 25% sized left column, and a 50% right content column with a 25% margin = 100%.

Here is a fiddle with 25% sidebar and 75% main with 0 margins.

http://jsfiddle.net/a2YSa/3/

Screenshot of my last fiddle:

[image]

Comment: The issue though, is that the content is at the bottom of the sidebar.  The content needs to be beside the sidebar.

Comment: Look at my fiddles, it is beside the sidebar.  The reason your content is falling beneath it is because you are calculating a total width greater than 100%, and so it breaks pushing the next div beneath the one that precedes it, which happens to be the content div.

Comment: I am looking at your fiddles Michael, however, the content is beside the sidebar but at the bottom; it needs to at top - thats where i am having the issue at.. I'll play around with it.  Because I got like 5 hours before the people get here to look at this lol

Comment: What browser are you using to view the fiddle.  It does not appear that way to me.  See my edit in a moment with a screenshot.

Comment: Weird.. I am using Firefox at the moment - but usually use Chrome.  However I think I gave this badboy a quick fix.. margin: -390px 20px; now just gotta mess with the footer.  This webpage isn't for me.. I am fixing to go pick up a CSS3 and HTML5 book lol

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using firebug to visualize the problem ? I think you should remove your 25% left margin on your #content...

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is here:

```
content width: 68%
content margin-left: 25%
sidebar width: 25%
```

you currently use more then 100%.
if that isn't the problem, please post html code too or check the width AND paddings / margins with Firebug. it's the easiest way.

Comment: so then change this values in your css for the content: margin:2px 0; padding:20px; if you need more space between your <aside> and the content, just increase the margin value form 0 to 10px or higher...